# Understanding R lm output with categorical variables

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, lm

I ran the following `lm` model:

`basic.model <- lm(Calmness.Score ~ Hours.of.Sleep*Age*Session*Group, data = df)`

Where `Group` is either `Increase` or `Decrease`

and get the output:

```
Coefficients:
                                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                      9.216702   0.917509  10.045  < 2e-16 ***
Hours.of.Sleep                                   0.011718   0.144869   0.081    0.936    
AgeOld                                           0.428732   1.113735   0.385    0.700    
SessionPost                                      0.088249   0.984970   0.090    0.929    
GroupIncrease                                   -5.517614   1.099951  -5.016 6.75e-07 ***
Hours.of.Sleep:AgeOld                           -0.050625   0.185079  -0.274    0.785    
Hours.of.Sleep:SessionPost                      -0.017409   0.156319  -0.111    0.911    
AgeOld:SessionPost                               0.161423   1.237322   0.130    0.896    
Hours.of.Sleep:GroupIncrease                     0.000511   0.175912   0.003    0.998    
AgeOld:GroupIncrease                            -2.292312   1.660497  -1.380    0.168    
SessionPost:GroupIncrease                       -1.279574   1.202226  -1.064    0.288    
Hours.of.Sleep:AgeOld:SessionPost               -0.026481   0.207104  -0.128    0.898    
Hours.of.Sleep:AgeOld:GroupIncrease              0.150822   0.285353   0.529    0.597    
Hours.of.Sleep:SessionPost:GroupIncrease         0.189191   0.193266   0.979    0.328    
AgeOld:SessionPost:GroupIncrease                 0.960861   1.836176   0.523    0.601    
Hours.of.Sleep:AgeOld:SessionPost:GroupIncrease -0.134828   0.315682  -0.427    0.669    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8693 on 674 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9278,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9261 
F-statistic:   577 on 15 and 674 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The 5th row of the coefficients `GroupIncrease` is significant. Does this mean that **only** the `Increase` Group is significant or is `R` randomly choosing a factor to display for the coefficients and both `Increase` and `Decrease` Groups have a significant associations with calmness score?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a categorical variable in a regression model, one of the categories is chosen as the "baseline" category and the model incorporates the other categories through indicator variables.  In the present case your coding leads to the `decrease` group being treated as the baseline and the `increase` group being treated as a deviation from that baseline.  The coefficient `GroupIncrease` is the coefficient that applies to the indicator variable for the latter category.

Now, with regards to the statistical significance of that outcome, this is saying that there is statistically significant evidence of a non-zero `GroupIncrease` coefficient, which is equivalent to saying that there is statistically significant evidence of a *difference* between the `decrease` and `increase` groups.  If you were to reverse the coding of these groups in the model, so that the `increase` group became the baseline group, this statistical test would still give you the exact same outcome, since the magnitude of the difference would be the same, but in the other direction.

In regards to the coefficient tests in regression, you should note that the null hypothesis for these tests is that the relevant model coefficient is zero and the alternative hypothesis is that the relevant model coefficient is non-zero.  In the case of a binary categorical variable, this means that the test is looking at whether or not there is a *difference* in the expected response variable (here your `Calmness.Score`) for the two categories.  For this type of test there is no way for `increase` to be "significant" and `decrease` to be insignificant because the test is looking at the *difference* in the response between these categories.

Answer (score 0):

Since Group is factor, the low value (i.e. Decrease) is incorporated into the Intercept and then thus to account for the high value (i.e. Increase) a separate variable "GroupIncrease" is introduced into the model.
One way to look at is the "GroupIncrease" variable models the change when the variable Group transitions from Decrease to Increase.
This interpretation can be applied to the other created variables, AgeOld and SessionPost. So yes, it appears that only the Intercept and transition of the Group variable in significant for this model.